# Where is the source for sensors in Nexus 5?

Tags: shared-libraries, sensors, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, hal

I could see some of the sources for sensors under **`hardware/*`** in the Android 4.4 source but the resulting shared libraries have a different name than the sensor shared libraries that I searched within the Nexus 5 under the **`/system/lib`** and **`/system/lib/hw`** or even under the entire root(**`/`**).

Nexus 5 reports to have sensors from InvenSense, Qualcomm, Avago, Bosch, and Akm. But, I am wondering whether their sensors' code is not open-sourced but only their binaries for sensor HAL modules(**`*.so`**).

By the way, below is the list of sensors(including virtual/synthetic sensors) being reported.

:: `Sensor name - Vendor` ::

```
 1. MPU6515 Accelerometer - InvenSense
 2. AK8963 Magnetometer - AKM
 3. AK8963 Magnetometer Uncalibrated - AKM
 4. MPU6515 Gyroscope - InvenSense
 5. MPU6515 Gyroscope Uncalibrated - InvenSense
 6. Proximity Proximity & Light - Avago
 7. Light Proximity & Light - Avago
 8. BMP280 Barometer - BOSCH
 9. Gravity - Qualcomm
 10. Linear Acceleration - Qualcomm
 11. Rotation Vector - Qualcomm
 12. Step Detector - Qualcomm
 13. Step Counter - Qualcomm
 14. Significant Motion Detector - Qualcomm
 15. Game Rotation Vector - Qualcomm
 16. Geomagnetic Rotation Vector - Qualcomm
 17. Orientation - Qualcomm
 18. MPU6515 Game Rotation Vector Secondary - InvenSense
```

Any idea where is the source for the above sensors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't provide the code for the sensor part and publish the sensor hal lib as binary file. You could find the library in one of the vendor files and the target path is /system/vendor/lib/hw.

Giuseppe.